# How to access a list made in one function under widget build for list creation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to take the `idslist` made under `downloadFile()` for making a list using list builder as shown below.
I know it must be a silly doubt, but I am kinda new to everything.

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  initState() {
    // this is called when the class is initialized or called for the first time
    super.initState();
    downloadFile(); //  this is the material super constructor for init state to link your instance initState to the global initState context
  }

  downloadFile() async {
    final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user!.uid;
    final reflinks = Database.ref().child(uid).child("Status");
    final idlinks = Database.ref().child(uid).child("ID");
    var idsnapshots = await idlinks.get();
    var snapshot = await reflinks.get();
    var prev = snapshot.value;
    var ids = idsnapshots.value;
    List<String> idslist = ids.toString().split(", ");

    var ran = Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < idslist.length; i++) {
      await saveImage(idslist[i], (ran.nextInt(10000)).toString() + ".jpg");
      return idslist;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
        return Image.network(idslist[index]);
      },
      itemCount: idslist.length,
    ));
  }
}
```

It says that `idslist` is not defined.
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Var idsnapshots = await idlinks.get();
  Where have you added this? Seems to be oitside the build method?

Comment: Please provide full code, for better answers

Comment: @KaushikChandru I have updated the q! I am sorry for not adding enough details

Answer (score 0):

Here downloadfile method is asynchronous. You missed to setstate after the data is loaded .

Also this variable

```dart
List <String>idslist
```

Is inside the download method. Move it outside the method. Same level as initstae and build methods